# Javascript & and | symbols

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

I know that `&&` and `||` are used in comparisons as `AND` and `OR`, respectively.

But what about the `&` and `|` operators? What are they used for?

Here's the code I'm testing:

```
var a = 2;
var b = 3;
var c = a & b;//2
var d = a | b;//3
```

Difference between && , || and &, | ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are bitwise AND and OR respectively. The usage is mainly for low-level (now don't why you would want that here, there may be many applications) operations.

For example:

```
Decimal Number    Binary Form
    20               10100
    30               11110

  20       ==>   10100
& 30       ==>   11110
-----           ----------
  20             10100  (when both bits are 1)

  20       ==>   10100
| 30       ==>   11110
-----           ----------
  30             11110  (when either of the bits is 1)
```

Similarly there are other operators too:

```
operator    meaning             example
xor (^)   only one bit is 1     1101
                               ^1001
                               ------
                                0100
```

I could provide the whole list but that would be of no use. Already many answers contain links to excellent resources. You might want to look at those. My answer just gives some idea.

Answer (score 4):

They are bitwise operators that operate on the bits of the number. You have to think the bits of the numbers in order for the result to make sense:

```
a = 2 //0010
b = 3 //0011
a & b; //0010 & 0011 === 0010 === 2
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

They are mainly used for reading and manipulating binary data, such as .mp3 files.

Comment: Do you know any site with an example of how to use these operators to manipulate mp3 files?

Comment: @MarkLinus here's javascript mp3 decoder library for example https://github.com/nddrylliog/jsmad

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has the same set of bitwise operators as Java:

```
& and
| or
^ xor
~ not
>> signed right shift
>>> unsigned right shift
<< left shift
```

In Java, the bitwise operators work with integers. JavaScript doesn't have integers. It only has double
precision floating-point numbers. **So, the bitwise operators convert their number operands into integers, do
their business, and then convert them back.**

e.g.:

```
a = 2 //0010
b = 3 //0011
a & b; //0010 & 0011 === 0010 === 2
a | b; //0010 | 0011 === 0011 === 3
```

In most languages, these operators are very close to the hardware
and very fast. In JavaScript, they are very far from the hardware and very slow. JavaScript is rarely used for
doing bit manipulation.
As a result, in JavaScript programs, it is more likely that `&` is a mistyped `&&` operator. The presence of the
bitwise operators reduces some of the language's redundancy, making it easier for bugs to hide

*Javascript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford* + Esailija answer

Comment: Please cite your source - this is a direct quote from _Javascript: The Good Parts_ by Douglas Crockford.

Comment: I was just going to cite it ;)

Comment: @user278064 now you copypasted the code directly (without even fixing missing semicolons) from my answer, might wanna cite that too ? :P

Comment: @Esailija: Missing semicolons is not an error in javascript, rather a bad practice which sometimes could lead to unexpected results :)

Answer (score 2):

The && and || are [logical operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), while & and | are [bitwise operators](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsoprbitwiseand.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The && and || are logical operators, while & and | are bitwise operators

[Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) - **Bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeros and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers. For example, the decimal number nine has a binary representation of 1001. Bitwise operators perform their operations on such binary representations, but they return standard JavaScript numerical values.**

assume the variable 'a' to be 13 (binary 1101) and 'b' to be 9 (binary 1001)

[Bitwise AND Operator (&) (JavaScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dazfy1f3%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) - This is the bitwise AND operator which returns a 1 for each bit position where the corresponding bits of both its operands are 1. The following code would return 9 (1001):

Code:

```
result = a & b;
```

[Bitwise OR Operator (|) (JavaScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/066h456z%28v=vs.94%29) - This is the bitwise OR operator and returns a one for each bit position where one or both of the corresponding bits of its operands is a one. This example would return 13 (1101):

Code:

```
result = a | b;
```

Read more

[OPERATORS:  & | ^ ~ << >> >>>](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/bitwise_operators.html)

Comment: they are binary AND and OR operators.